# Function to compute number of periods between two dates

Tags: vba

Suppose the flow of time is subdivided into *periods*:

- *Period 1* beginning August and ending January
- *Period 2* beginning February and ending July

Note, that each period is 6 month.

**Question**

> Now suppose two dates A and B are given.
>
> Could you provide an **expression (closed formula),** which computes the
>   **number of periods** where A is within the first and B is within the last
>   period?
>
> 'Closed formula' :: The creation of a procedure isn't an option her.

**Let's have a detailed look**

Let...

- *A* be the 2nd of March 2015
- *B* be the 15th of January 2018

Thus...

- A is part of period 2 beginning February 2015.
- B is part of period 1 beginning August 2017.

Therefore...

- **the difference in periods between A and B is 6.**

Since

- Period 2 beginning February **2015**
- Period 1 beginning August 2015
- Period 2 beginning February **2016**
- Period 1 beginning August 2016
- Period 2 beginning February **2017**
- Period 1 beginning August 2017

Comment: Are you looking for an VBA or Excel formula solution? Are the periods always 6 monthes or can you have one with 4 and the other with 8 monthes?

Comment: @FunThomas Each period is 6 month.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear: If *"creation of a procedure isn't an open"*, do you mean no VBA but an Excel formula? Then you should change the tag of your question.

Comment: Plus: Are you sure that the difference is 6? I guess it is 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into the VBA function DateDiff https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datediff-function

Answer (score 0):

Code to test your function. Insert a **module** in the VBA editor and enter the following code in it:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function CountPeriods(startDate As Date, endDate As Date) As Long
    Dim diffMonths As Long
    Dim diffPeriods As Long

    diffMonths = DateDiff("m", startDate, endDate)
    diffPeriods = diffMonths \ 6
    CountPeriods = diffPeriods
End Function
```

Now enter your start and end dates and refer to the code above like this in cell B1 (or any cell):

[image]

Comment: Not quite correct for all dates but it will give you a starting point

Comment: This doesn't handle the fact that any dates < 6 month can be within the same period or within 2 different.

Comment: Just wrote that

Answer (score 0):

As formula (assuming your date in A2 and B2):

```
=(YEAR(EDATE(A2;-1))*2+INT((MONTH(EDATE(A2;-1))-1)/6)) - (YEAR(EDATE(B2;-1))*2+INT((MONTH(EDATE(B2;-1))-1)/6))
```

As VBA function:

```
Function datePeriods(ByVal d1 As Date, ByVal d2 As Date) As Long
    d1 = DateAdd("m", -1, d1)
    d2 = DateAdd("m", -1, d2)
    Dim p1 As Long, p2 As Long
    p1 = Year(d1) * 2 + ((Month(d1) - 1) \ 6)
    p2 = Year(d2) * 2 + ((Month(d2) - 1) \ 6)
    datePeriods = p2 - p1
End Function
```

The basic idea is to "move" the periods to the first and second half of a year, then calculate a numeric value for the year (`year * 2`) and the "half year" (integer division by 6) and subtract these two values.